# How do i call jquery variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

This is very simple i am sure but i am new to jquery and am kinda stuck.

I wrote this code which works perfectly:

```
function engageMaps(){
  $(".destinations #cancun").hover(
    function () {
      $(".image_map #cancunPin").addClass("active");
    },
    function () {
      $(".image_map #cancunPin").removeClass("active");
    }
  );
};
```

Then I tried to break items out into variables to make it more flexible but can't get it to work. I wrote this:

```
function engageMaps(){
  var $destination = $(".destinations #cancun");
  var pin = $(".image_map #cancunPin");
  $destination.hover(
    function () {
      $pin.addClass("active");
    },
    function () {
      $pin.removeClass("active");
    }
};
```

This should be exactly the same as the first code block. Any help is much appreciated thanks

Comment: your variable is `$pin` in one place and `pin` in another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `);` for `.hover`..

```
$destination.hover(
   function () {
     $pin.addClass("active");
   },
   function () {
     $pin.removeClass("active");
   }
);
```

Also you missed `$`. See below.

```
var $pin = $(".image_map #cancunPin");
```

**Full code:**

```
function engageMaps(){
  var $destination = $(".destinations #cancun");
  var $pin = $(".image_map #cancunPin"); //Added $ to pin var name as that is how it is referenced below

  $destination.hover(
    function () {
      $pin.addClass("active");
    },
    function () {
      $pin.removeClass("active");
    }
   ); //this was missing
} //removed semicolon as it is not necessary
```

Comment: Also, the variable pin doesn't have a dollar sign when it is initialized and does when called, they are different variables.

Answer (score 4):

```
    v---------- You forgot this
var $pin = $(".image_map #cancunPin");
```

And also you are missing `);` for `.hover`.

So, the final version of the code:

```
function engageMaps() {
    var $destination = $(".destinations #cancun");
    var $pin = $(".image_map #cancunPin");
    $destination.hover(
        function() {
            $pin.addClass("active");
        }, function() {
            $pin.removeClass("active");
        }
    );
};​
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$destination.hover(
    function () {
      $pin.toggleClass("active");
    });
```

So complete code is:

```
function engageMaps(){
  var $destination = $(".destinations #cancun");
  var $pin = $(".image_map #cancunPin"); // you use pin instead of $pin
  $destination.hover(
    function () {
      $pin.toggleClass("active");
  });
};
```

Comment: I am curious to see how `hover` and `toggleClass` will work.. like `mouseenter` first time `addClass`.. `mouseout` nothing happens.. then `mouseenter` again and `toggleClass` will `removeClass`.. This is not a desired effect. I don't think `toggleClass` works as intended with `hover`.

Comment: @Vega no, no, its ok. I'm here to learn and help. what's your think about this behavior of hover.

Comment: My assumption was wrong.. `hover` with one function argument will be a `handlerInOut(eventObject)` - Which is a function to execute when the mouse pointer enters or leaves the element. So now it all makes sense.

Comment: @Vega I knew that from source code, but an explanation from someone like you gives me more detail and elegant info. thanks